# Flyway Community version with old database

Tags: database, database-migration, flyway

Suppose I have a running database with Flyway.

I am with the same database and Flyway version (artifact) six years later.

Since Flyway 8.0.0-beta1, database versions older than five years have deprecated support (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.0.0-beta1).

So, does that mean that any Flyway version will not work with older databases? Does it just mean that current versions of Flyway will not work with older databases? Is this just about support and not about not working?

Example: Flyway 8.0 works with MySQL 5.5 or higher, and Flyway 9.0 works with MySQL 8.0 or higher. If I am still with Flyway 8.0 and MySQL 5.5 after six years, will Flyway still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (The Flyway Team) have removed this restriction in Flyway Version 10 so you can now use the latest version of Flyway with older versions of MySQL.  This means Flyway will continue to work for you after 6 years.